# nvprof shows error with TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, nvprof, nvvp

I am trying to run nvprof with `cifar10_multigpu_train.py`.
I am using following command

```
/home/ibm/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda/bin/nvprof python cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py
```

It starts the application but after sometime it shows following errors and application exits.

```
==140659== Warning: Some profiling data are not recorded. Make sure cudaProfilerStop() or cuProfilerStop() is called before application exit to flush profile data.
======== Error: Application received signal 11
```

Any idea whats going wrong. File runs just fine without using nvprof.

Note: I have 0.12.0 version installed and I am on IBM PPC64le machine.

Comment: Have you tried running with TensorFlow 1.0?